# How to install the newest GNOME 2 global menu?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, globalmenu

I'd like to install the newest version of GNOME 2 global menu that is used in Natty. But the only thing I could find was version `0.7.10` : http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/downloads/list

But this old version can't export Firefox 4 menus. It was updated in 2010.:(

Can I get that from Natty ? How?

Answer (score 1):

gnome 2 global menu is not used on natty, it uses a global menu but it doesn't use that you mention

Answer (score 0):

The global menu in Natty is provided by the Unity shell, which is a separate thing built on top of Gnome (Gnome2, currently). Therefore, you have a few potential options:

1. Install Unity (I'm not sure if it's officially available for Maverick, but I don't see why it wouldn't work)
2. Update to Natty
3. If you don't like Unity, update to Natty and install Gnome3 from the Gnome team PPA (somewhat risky, as it kills Unity, because Unity currently runs on Gnome2; I haven't had any trouble or need to revert, but if you're not sure you'd like Gnome3, I recommend doing a dry run in VirtualBox)
4. If you feel adventurous and can't/don't want to update to Natty, compile Gnome3 from source and install it (probably most risky)
5. Find a different shell, or see if there's a plugin of some sort for Gnome2